# Couldn't keep the button default state as clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

On loading of the website, the navbar's expected design is [image: The expected design of the website]

I have tried this, but wasn't able to set the button's state as clicked.

The output I achieved in video format : https://files.fm/u/zpnp3t2ee

[image]

Comment: Please do review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As-is, we can't help if we can't see what your code is doing.

Comment: I hope code isn't needed for every question. It's a very simple code for button and styles on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with input radio buttons.
Which ever [type="radio"] that is checked, will have the colored bottom border.

Note: I'm using [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) for the menu icons.

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
}
.menu .menu-item {
  cursor: default;
  display: inline;
}
.menu .menu-item [type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
.menu .menu-item [type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #080;
}
.menu .menu-item label {
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <input type="radio" name="MenuItem" id="MenuItemDashboard" value="Dashboard" checked>
        <label for="MenuItemDashboard"><span class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></span> Dashboard</label>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <input type="radio" name="MenuItem" id="MenuItemClasses" value="Classes">
        <label for="MenuItemClasses"><span class="fa fa-chalkboard"></span> Classes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <input type="radio" name="MenuItem" id="MenuItemTimeTable" value="TimeTable">
        <label for="MenuItemTimeTable"><span class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></span> Time Table</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't working when I replace label with <a> tag as I am using this for navigation. https://codepen.io/sravvya_malla/pen/VwPrgvy

Comment: Why use "a" tag for this?

"a" tags does not have the attribute "for", only labels has that. So if you want to trigger the input with a "a" tag, you need some JavaScript.